# Release Multimodule Maven project with multiple git repositories

Tags: java, git, maven

I have a multimodule maven project, previously I was able to release the project easily when all the modules resided on the same git repository but now I had to move some modules to another git repository and I can't figure out how can I release the whole project in one run, any ideas?

Comment: Simply does not work, cause it does not make sense to have separated git repository for a multi module build. Furthermore which git repository should be tagged with which tag?

Comment: Please show your directory structures before and after.